# Kubernetes event logs to elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, fluentd

I'm trying to forward kubernetes-event logs to elasticsearch using fluentd.I currently use `fluent/fluentd-kubernetes-daemonset:v1.10.1-debian-elasticsearch7-1.0`as container image to forward my application logs to elasticsearch cluster.I've searched enough & my problem is that this image doesn't have enough documentation as to accomplishing this task(i.e; forward kubernetes event related logs).

I've found [this](https://rubygems.org/gems/fluent-plugin-kubernetes-objects) plugin from splunk which has desired output but this has overhead like :

- add above plugin's gem to bundler.
- install essential tools like `make` etc.
- install the plugin .

Sure I can do above steps using `init-container`, but above operations are adding ~200MB to disk space .I'd like to know if it can be accomplished with smaller footprint or other way.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can try this: https://github.com/opsgenie/kubernetes-event-exporter

It is able to export Kube events to Elasticsearch.